# How to call my some script after to work out google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-tag-manager

I have google tag manager snippet in my header, he adds some arguments to my links. I wont parse this links AFTER work out this manager.
How do I do this?

For the moment I can start my function only with `setTimeout`, but I thing  is not correct.

In this case, the manager does not work at all, nothing is displayed in the console.
This code is located in the header
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

nothing errors in `console`

Comment: "I wont parse this links AFTER work out this manager" What does this mean?

Comment: how it works:
1.uploaded DOM (there are some products links)
2.runs a google tag manager (it adds some arguments to the links)
3. I want to parse these links using jquery.but my script works before the arguments are added and I can not get these arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a [Custom HTML tag](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107167?hl=en#CustomHTML) in GTM that fires a JavaScript event that you can listen for.

```
<script>
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('gtm:loaded'))
</script>
```

Then, in your source code, listen for that event.

```
window.addEventListener('gtm:loaded', function (event) {
  // give the necessary tag a chance to run
  setTimeout(function () {
    // your code
  }, 500)
})
```

Note, you'll need to use a polyfill for `CustomEvent` if you want to support IE.

```
(function () {

  if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false;

  function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
    params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
    var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
    return evt;
   }

  CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

  window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

Comment: when I use this example `gtm` does not work.
can you help me?

Comment: Sure.  Can you please elaborate on what you mean when you say that `gtm` does not work?  What is `gtm`?

Comment: `gtm` is google tag manager. Is it possible to better use mail for our communication?

Comment: how it works: 1.uploaded DOM (there are some products links) 2.runs a google tag manager (it adds some arguments to the links) 3. I want to parse these links using jquery.but my script works before the arguments are added and I can not get these arguments. BUT were i use your example, 'gtm' does not work - not added some arguments to links.

Comment: To be clear, after attempting to implement the code in this answer, all of Google Tag Manager is not working?

If so, please outline exactly what you have done.  Please also include screenshots of code snippets.  Please also share any `console` errors that you are seeing.

The code included in this example should not affect the GTM container in any way.

Comment: i add screenshots to my question